# Oracle - find position of a delimiter(;) in multi-string if it is present at the beginning of a line

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
SELECT  REGEXP_INSTR('1234;67;89
;
',';') FROM DUAL;
```

Output:
5

I want the position of the ; present at the beginning of the line. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `m` match parameter and modify you pattern to `^;`

```
    SELECT  REGEXP_INSTR('1234;67;89;
    ;
    ','^;',1, 1, 1, 'm') FROM DUAL;
```

Output:

```
13
```

More in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions129.htm)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_INSTR('1234;67;89
;
'
,'(^|'||chr(10)||');') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: If the input string is `;1234\n;` this answer would get the location of the second `;` not the one at the beginning of the string (and you also need to add one to the location as you are getting the position of the newline character). It is unclear from the OP's question if this is the desired behaviour but if it is then you do not need to use regular expressions and could do `INSTR( str, CHR(10)||';')+1`.

Comment: @MT0 - Yes, you are correct, thank you. My answer was not checked beginning `;` for first line.  edited.

Comment: The updated query will return 1 for both `';'` and `'\n;'` but the second string has the `;` at the second character.